# Internal ellipse formed by vertices of a pentagonal star

Tags: conic-sections, projective-geometry

$(A,C,D,E)$ are four fixed points on a fixed outer (red) ellipse and $B$ is a variable point lying between $A$ and $C$. Alternate vertices are joined to form a pentagonal star. (drawn on *Geogebra*).

A variable green inner ellipse circumscribing pentagon  $(abcde) $ is formed by connecting five internal points of intersection. The green ellipse size and orientation, eccentricity etc. geometric properties are functions of position of $B$ on arc $AC$ as shown. If $B$ does not lie between  $(A,C)$ then the green ellipse is not formed at all.

How are equations of red and green ellipses related with respect to the moving point $ B ? $ Do they have any common geometrical property? Can one property be obtained from the other?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: A failed approach: $(a^2-a)(y^2-y)=(b^2-b)(x^2-x)$ is the conic through $(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1),(a,b)$. If $0<a<1$ and $b>1$ then the five new points are $(\frac12,\frac12),(\frac{a}{b},1),(\frac{b-a+1}{b},1),(\frac{b}{b-a+1},\frac{b}{b-a+1}),(\frac{a}{b+a},\frac{b}{b+a})$ which from the 6 by 6 determinant yields a unwieldy new conic equation in terms of a and b.

Comment: The third point should be $(\frac{b-a}{b},1)$ and then the equation becomes $-(a-1)b^2x^2+(2a-1)b(b-a)xy+a(b^2-2ab+b+2a^2-2a)y^2-ab(b-2a+1)x-a(2b^2-2ab+a^2-a)y+ab(b-a)$

Comment: It  appears something is nicely coming up. May be  if another symbol like $c$ for $1$ is used a homogeneous equation would show up with symmetry?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. Are you starting with a conic $C_1$, or are you starting with five distinguished points defining $C_1$? If it is five points, I can see how pairwise intersections would lead to a second conic, but it feels as though the conics were mostly defined in terms of their points, with little connection to be expected between $C_1$ and $C_2$. If all you have is the conic $C_1$, I fail to see how $C_2$ is defined from that, since picking five different points would lead to a different conic. Can you clarify this?

Comment: I am replacing the question to a much narrower context, May be it could be generalized later. Please indicate if it makes sense.

Comment: Clearer now, thanks. Seeing how the construction is invariant under projective transformations, and with the projective-geometry tag applied to the question, I'd suggest using the unit circle, i.e. choosing $A=[1:0:1]$, $B=[1-t^2:2t:1+t^2]$ with $t\in(0,1)$, $C=[0:1:1]$, $D=[-1:0:1]$, $E=[0:-1:1]$, but this would not be able to express metric properties like foci and eccentricity and such that you might be interested in. Are you, or would that choice be without loss of generality as far as your question is concerned?

Comment: Frankly, I am indifferent how we get there, as indicated and deleted in earlier, question based on raw intuition. If Pascal's hexagon crumbled into an ellipse has collinear intersections, what invariant or property is hidden among less crumpled pentagon (inscribed in ellipse) intersections here?